# A question about polynomial over finite field

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

For the positive integer $m$, let $n=\varphi(m)$ denote the totient of $m$. 
Given a rational prime $p$ such that $p\equiv 1 \bmod m$, let $A=\{a_1,\cdots, a_n\}\subseteq \mathbb{F}_p$ denote the set of elements in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ with order $m$. Pick $n-1$ elements from the set $A$ arbitrarily, say $a_1,...,a_{n-1}$, and define $f(x)=(x-a_1)\cdots (x-a_{n-1})$ to be a polynomial in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

My question is: according to the experimental data, the coefficients of $f(x)$ are all non-zero. But I do not know how to prove or refute this propostion.

Can you help me out? Thanks very much!

Comment: Let’s see, it looks as if you are choosing one, say $\alpha$, of the $\varphi(m)$ elements of $\Bbb F_p$ of period $m$, and looking at the polynomial $\Phi_m(X)/(X-\alpha)$, and noticing that this polynomial has no zero-coefficients? (Here $\Phi_m$ is the $m$-th cyclotomic polynomial.)

Comment: Yes, our descriptions are equivalent. And yours seems better than mine. Actually, I am not sure about the correctness of this proposition. A proof, or a sufficient condition for the correctness of this proposition, is preferred.

Comment: I would try it with $p=211$ and $m=105$, since $\Phi_{105}$ is the first “interesting” cyclotomic polynomial. Offhand, I see no reason why the conjecture should be true.

Comment: I recall a different but vaguely similar lemma: If $\alpha$ is a generator of the multiplicative group of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ of $q$ element, and $d \leq q - 1$ is a positive integer then the polynomial $(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^2)\cdots(x-\alpha^{d-1}) \in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ has nonzero coefficients. I hope to find the proof somewhere in my notes (not my own work).

Comment: Following up on Jon's great suggestion, 16 is a root of $\Phi_{105}$ modulo 211 and the coefficient of $x^{20}$ of $\Phi_{105}/(x-16)$ is zero.

Comment: The proposition works when $m$ is prime, of course, but it seems hard to make  general (true) statement for general $m$.

Comment: It is also true that $\frac{x^{m}-1}{x- \alpha}$ has non-zero coefficients whenever $\alpha^{m} = 1$.

Comment: Yes, it fails when $m=105$. Many thanks to all of you!!